# Possible to simulate specific chess situations?

Tags: engines, stockfish

I played around with [cutechess](https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess) and [stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/) to simulate a specific situation in chess. But I ended up playing complete games against a human or cpu. Is it even possible to set up a chess situation by hand and let the chess engine compute solutions?

Comment: Stockfish has a built-in n analysis and annotation mode.

Comment: I think you want to use the "setup position" functionality available in several chess softwares.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Fritz (or any other engine under the ChessBase GUI) to do this, using the "Infinite Analysis" function, so it's definitely possible, though I have no experience with other chess software and therefore don't know how to do this with other GUIs.

As for simulations, it is possible to have the engine play many games against itself, available in the ChessBase GUI again, called Monte Carlo analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I ended up using [jerry](http://asdfjkl.github.io/jerry/) which is very easy to use, platform independent and also supportes various engines. Recommend it.